# C# Excel Macro - how to check if cell value is negative and change its font colour?

Tags: c#, excel

I need to check if cells value is negative or positive, if negative - change its font colour to red. This is how I tried to do it, it doesn't work...

```
                oRange2 = oWorksheet.get_Range("L14");
                int value = oRange2.Value;

                if(value < 0)
                {
                    oRange2.Font.ColorIndex = 3;
                }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use Excel's conditional formatting?

Comment: because I have to do all that stuff in SSIS. But maybe I will try to write a VBA script instead of C#

Comment: I don't know C# so this question might sound dumb, but does C# truncate values when converting to integer, or does it round to the lower integer, or round to the nearer integer, or something else?  Just wondering what would happen if L14 contained the number `-0.4` - will `value` be set to `-1` or to `0`?

Comment: A custom number format like `general;[red]general;general;@` will do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

A custom number format like `[Red][<0]General;General` will do this for you. If you don't like that particular shade of red then `[color9][<0]General;General` provides a darker palette.

```
oWorksheet.get_Range("L14").NumberFormat = "[Red][<0]General;General";
//... or for the whole column
oWorksheet.get_Range("L14").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "[color9][<0]General;General";
// red with brackets
oWorksheet.get_Range("L14").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "[Red][<0](General);General_)"
// red with minus sign
oWorksheet.get_Range("L14").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "[Red][<0]-General;General"
```

I've used `General` as you did not supply any example data but you could easily substitute some sort of fixed or floating decimal number mask.

Comment: It works! :) but it makes number positive, I mean: before it was -5 and now it is 5, how can I make this numer be still negative?

Comment: You can add brackets or a minus sign to show negative values; e.g. `[Red][<0](General);General_)` for brackets, the `_)` adds a right-most space to positive numbers so the digits line up. See [Custom Number Format Codes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) for full details.